# Establishing relation in partial derivatives.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

> Let $f$ be a function of $x$ and $y$, where $x=u+v-uv$ and $y=uv-u$. Find $\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}$in terms of $\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u^2}$, $\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u\partial v}$ and $\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial v^2}$.

I got $$\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u^2}=f_{xu}(1-v)+f_{yu}(v-1)$$
$$\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial v^2}= f_{xv}(1-u)+f_{yv}u$$
$$\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u\partial v}=f_{xu}(1-u)+f_x(-1)+f_{yu}u+f_y$$

How do I get $\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}$ as there is no such term generated?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have done the derivatives incorrectly. For example, the first one should be

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u^2} & = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}[1-v] + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}[v-1] \bigg) \\
& = \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(1-v) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(v-1) \bigg)[1-v] + \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(1-v) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(v-1)\bigg)[v-1] \\
& = (1-v)^2\bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - 2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \bigg)
\end{align}

I leave the rest to you.

**EDIT:**

Apologies. What you have done is not incorrect. You just need to apply the chain rule once more.

For example, you have

$$\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u^2}=f_{xu}(1-v)+f_{yu}(v-1)$$

but the $f_{xu}$ can be further decomposed as

$$f_{xu} = [f_x]_u = [f_x]_xx_u + [f_x]_yy_u$$